# Remove duplicates and get the count based on 2 sub criteria in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I appreciate if you can take a look at the below code and help me further as I'm stuck badly. below code helps me get the unique list of names from the Selection and their respective count. This code uses the "Scripting.Dictionary". However there is 1 more additional header, that is the "Date"; so the desired output would be based on the Date as well as showing in the picture. I have tried everything I could, but failed.

My Current Output based on the code

[image: My Current Output based on the code]

```
    Sub vbacodechecker()

Dim d As Object, rng As Range, tmp As String
Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.dictionary")

    For Each rng In Selection
        tmp = Trim(rng.Value)
            If Len(tmp) > 0 Then d(tmp) = d(tmp) + 1
    Next rng

Range("B1").Select

    For Each k In d.keys
        ActiveCell.Offset(i + 1, 1).Value = k
        ActiveCell.Offset(i + 1, 2).Value = d(k)

    i = i + 1
    Next k
End Sub
```

Desired Output, names unique date wise

[[image: Desired Output, names unique date wise][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Fwrz.png)

Comment: Create a composite dictionary key by concatenating the name and the date with (eg) `|` and then split the key when populating to the sheet

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was able to do this by concatenating both "date" and "selection", and then further crack them into pieces using the delimiter and instr function for an end result.

Comment: Good to hear you worked it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach would be to use Power Query, available in Excel 2010+.

Just select to do Group By \ Selection & Date \ Count rows

[image]

**M-Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Selection", "Date"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), type number}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

**Source Data**

[image]

**Results**

[image]

Comment: Sorry, my project was prepared basis VBA only hence the pivot and power query wasn't the first option to achieve this. Appreciate your help in this.